# Xamarin Studio addin ProjectTemplate edit default identifier

Tags: xml, add-in, xamarin-studio

In my ProjectTemplate I would like to set the default Identifier property to something different then 'com.companyname'.

[image: Identifier]

I looked online but couldn't find any documentation on how to do this. Is it even possible? Here is the TemplateConfiguration from my .xpt file.

```
<TemplateConfiguration>
        <_Name>Test Xamarin.Forms App</_Name>
        <Category>crossplat/app/forms</Category>
        <Image file = "Resources/test-image.png" />
        <LanguageName>C#</LanguageName>
        <Wizard>Xamarin.Forms.ProjectTemplateWizard</Wizard>
        <_Description><![CDATA[Creates Xamarin.Forms Project using a Shared Project or Portable Class Library Project for code sharing.]]></_Description>
</TemplateConfiguration>
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? I am just wondering why the blue info icons are missing their right hand edge.

Comment: @MattWard Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Thanks. The Xamarin.Forms wizard looks pretty bad on Windows 10 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible using the Xamarin.Forms.ProjectTemplateWizard. The Identifier is com.companyname by default unless the author information is filled in (Preferences - Environment - Author Information). The Xamarin.Forms.ProjectTemplateWizard would need to be changed to support this.

The only way to do this would be to implement your own wizard page.